# Discord.js create JSON file with server information

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

Using discord.json, is there any way I can create a json file containing all information for a specific server? (Roles, channels, etc.)

No, I’m not asking for code. I’m asking whether or not this would be possible and if there’s a function for it.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the core module `fs` to make files (or a json file for your need)